# Hide element inside same parent by class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onclick

Take the following html:

```
<div class="box">
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="toggle_content(1)">Toggle</a>
<h2>Some Title</h2>
<div class="box_content box_content_1"></div>
<div class="box_content box_content_2"></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="toggle_content(1)">Toggle</a>
<h2>Some Title</h2>
<div class="box_content box_content_1"></div>
<div class="box_content box_content_2"></div>
</div>

<script>
function toggle_content(key){
   $('.box_content_'+key,$(this).parent()).toggle();
}
</script>
```

Basically, when the toggle link is clicked, I would like the toggle the element inside the same parent that has the matching class name. The code above doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11941911/1250044

Comment: @yckart I have revised my question to make it more clear of the situation.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Did not know exactly what you mean...

Comment: As a side-note, try not to hard-code script inside your html mark up. Try to place your scripts into a separate file and attach events through the use of `click()`, `on()`, `bind()` or `degate()`, though `on()` is the preferred option since jQuery 1.7. This will keep your html nice and clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the context of `this` in `toggle_content` by using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

```
onclick="toggle_content.call(this, 1)"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eyWBq/

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).parent()` doesn't refer to what you think it does. What is `this` in this context? Window.

The following will work:

```
$('.box_content_'+key,".box").toggle();
```

I would do it this way, though:

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="toggle" data-toggle-id="1">Toggle</a>
```

jQuery

```
$(".toggle").click(function() {
  var key = $(this).data("toggle-id");
  console.log(key);
  $('.box_content_'+key, $(this).parent()).toggle();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/oyagep/1)

Comment: sorry, this won't work, please see my revised example. there is a chance that there is more than one .box and .box_content_1. I thought this was the item being clicked on.

Comment: @David the first thing I have is just to show you why what you tried wouldn't work. The second half of my answer is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using jQuery you can use the jQuery `click` and `siblings()` methods, try the following:

> Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

```
$('.box a').click(function(){
   $(this).siblings('.box_content_1').toggle()
})
```

---

You can use `data=*` attribute for selecting the target elements of the anchors:

```
<div class="box">
   <a href="#" data-toggle="1">Toggle</a>
   <h2>Some Title</h2>
   <div class="box_content box_content_1"></div>
   <div class="box_content box_content_2"></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
   <a href="#" data-toggle="2">Toggle</a>
   <h2>Some Title</h2>
   <div class="box_content box_content_1"></div>
   <div class="box_content box_content_2"></div>
</div>
```

```
$('.box a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var which = $(this).data('toggle');
    $(this).siblings('.box_content_'+ which).toggle()
})
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to account for the dynamic element of the OP's question. He's passing a parameter that you have hard coded.

Comment: @j08691 This is funny, you have always a reason for downvoting my answers :)

Comment: I rarely downvote answers, period. Your original answer was incomplete. I have since removed the downvote.

Comment: @j08691 Yes, it's reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tveyF/)**.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="toggle_content(1,$(this))">Toggle</a>
<h2>Some Title</h2>
<div class="box_content box_content_1">a</div>
<div class="box_content box_content_2">b</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="toggle_content(2,$(this))">Toggle</a>
<h2>Some Title</h2>
<div class="box_content box_content_1">a</div>
<div class="box_content box_content_2">b</div>
</div>​
```

**jQuery**

```
function toggle_content(key,link){
   link.siblings(".box_content_"+key).toggle();
}​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/VLhQw/)**

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer to you!

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
    <a href="javascript:toggle_content(1);">Toggle</a>
    <h2>Some Title</h2>
    <div class="box_content box_content_1">1</div>
    <div class="box_content box_content_2">2</div>
</div>
```

**​JS:**

```
function toggle_content(key) {
    $('.box_content_' + key).toggle();

}​
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PWvsj/)**

Comment: That will also toggle any other element outside the same parent with the class of `.box_content_x`. OP requested only the elements inside the same parent.